# Adding a Pandas Dataframe-column to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas, I have some data that I want to add to my ``results'' dataframe. That is, I have

naics = someData

Which can look like this

```
   indnaics  ind1990
89    81393      873
```

however, it can have more than one row. I want to add these to my `results` dataframe, together with a variable called year. In case there is more than one row, it should be the same `year` value for all rows. This is what I am trying so far

```
for job in jobs:
    df2 =  iGetThisFromJob()
    years = df2.year.unique()
    naics = iGetThisFromJob()
    if len(naics) == 0:
        continue

    for year in years:
        wages = df2.incwage[df2.year == year]
    # Add all the data to results, this is how I try it
        rows = pd.DataFrame([dict(year=year, incwage=mean(wages), )])
    # I also want to add the column indnaics from my naics 
        rows['naics'] = naics.indnaics
        results = results.append(rows, ignore_index=True)
```

However, despite naics.indnaics being full, I cannot add it this way to the rows object.

> > > naics.indnaics

```
Out[1052]: 
89    81393
```

> > > rows['naics'] = naics.indnaics
> > >       rows

```
Out[1051]: 
        incwage  year naics
0  45853.061224  2002   NaN
```

If there is anything else that is not nice with my code, please tell. I'm only beginning to learn pandas.

Thanks!

/edit
Expected output:

```
        incwage  year   naics
0  45853.061224  2002   81393
0  45853.061224  2002   12312
```

/edit
Suggested solution:

```
index = arange(0, len(naics))
columns = ['year', 'incwage', 'naics']
rows = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
rows.year = year
rows.incwage = mean(wages)
rows.naics = naics.indnaics.values
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example dataframe to illustrate the problem? And also what the expected output would be with that example. So an example `df2` and `naics`

Comment: I thought my output in the end was sufficient - it displays the format of naics, and also what rows actually becomes (NaN - instead of becoming 81393)

Comment: And df2 is actually irrelevant for the part of my question, since that part of the code works (incwage and year both have the correct values) - I just left it in to give the right idea on what I'm trying to do

Comment: It always difficult to guess what is going on, and certainly to see how to fix it if you can't quickly try it out yourself (unless it is something really obvious). So therefore try to always provide a short self-contained example we can run (see http://www.sscce.org/). Furthermore, it is quite possible that you can do the whole for loop much simpler but it is diffucult to advise if we don't know what is going on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a NaN value, is because the index does not match (in `rows['naics'] = naics.indnaics` `rows` has index 0, while `naics.indnaics` has index 89), and assigning the value will try to align the indices.

You could for example solve that by taking only the value (by eg `naics.indnaics.values`). With a toy example:

```
In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0], 'B':[1]})
In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
   A  B
0  0  1


In [32]: s = pd.Series([2], index=[83])
In [33]: s
Out[33]: 
83    2
dtype: int64

In [35]: df['new_column'] = s
In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
   A  B  new_column
0  0  1         NaN

In [37]: df['new_column'] = s.values
In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
   A  B  new_column
0  0  1           2
```

If you want to add the series with possibly more values, there are a couple of options. I think of:

Eg reindexing the dataframe first to the length of the series:

```
In [75]: s
Out[75]: 
83    2
84    4
dtype: int64

In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
   A  B
0  0  1

In [77]: df = df.reindex(np.zeros(len(s)))
In [78]: df
Out[78]: 
   A  B
0  0  1
0  0  1

In [79]: df['new_column'] = s.values

In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
   A  B  new_column
0  0  1           2
0  0  1           4
```

or the other way around, add the dataframe to the series (that you first convert to a dataframe):

```
In [90]: ss = s.to_frame().set_index(np.array([0,0]))
In [91]: ss[df.columns] = df
In [92]: ss
Out[92]: 
   0  A  B
0  2  0  1
0  4  0  1

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: That works when naics contains one row, but not when it has two. It raises `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
`

Comment: OK, but what would be the expected output then? How can you add two elements to one column (when the dataframe has only one row)?

Comment: It should repeat the other values - I added that to the /edit in the question. I thought this would be standard behavior of pandas, if there wasn't this index issue.

Comment: You are adding a column to a dataframe, so that will only add a column, and not change the rest of the columns

Comment: Okay. So I guess there is no cleaner way than my last edit in the question?

Comment: Yes, your solution seems the cleanest to me for this particular problem. But as I said, it could be that you can do it a lot simpler, but that is very difficult to say without a working code example.